# How to upload multiple summaries to a release stage in Azure DevOps Server 2020?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am used to run the [uploadsummary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#uploadsummary-add-some-markdown-content-to-the-build-summary) logging command to add custom information to my builds.

However, I noticed that whereas it is OK to upload multiple summaries for a build (they will be displayed one after another), only the first one sticks to a release stage.

Observe:

**Build**

```
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.uploadsummary]D:\_wf\06\233\s\Summary1.md
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.uploadsummary]D:\_wf\06\233\s\Summary2.md
```

[image]

**Release**

```
2021-09-13T16:30:14.4533447Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.uploadsummary]D:\_wf\02\r1\a\source\Summary1.md
2021-09-13T16:30:14.4536640Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.uploadsummary]D:\_wf\02\r1\a\source\Summary2.md
```

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong? Or is it a bug in Azure DevOps Server 2020?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to upload multiple summaries to a release stage in Azure DevOps Server 2020?

I could reproduce this issue with Azure DevOps Server 2020 and Azure DevOps Services.

It seems that multiple summaries in one task of the release pipeline are not parsed into multiple summaries, but are overwritten. This may be an unexpected issue, but at least it needs to be confirmed with the product team.

**To resolve** this issue, you could try to use two task to upload the `Summary1.md` and `Summary2.md`.

I test it and it works fine on my side:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The logic is spread across multiple Powershell scripts invoked from a single task. This makes it harder, but I will try.

Comment: This suggestion solved my problem, thank you.